# load info from database without refreshing the whole page

Tags: php, mysql

i need help with this...plz ?

[image]

this photo from facebook

the "older posts" button.......how can i make some thing like that for my site...i want to load news from database without refreshing the whole page...

thanks

Comment: It is called AJAX, and it is a full world of opportunities. You won't get ready-to-paste answers. Just look for a good tutorial on the net.

Comment: Given how vague the question is all I can give as an answer is that you need to use AJAX.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use JavaScript and make an asynchronous request to the server. This is done through AJAX. I don't know your specific code, so I cannot tell you more than this. If you want an advice, jQuery gives you very friendly API to do AJAX requests to the server.

Regards

Comment: +1 jquery is good but somewhat misleading, because people often use it in a "dumb" way ignoring all the internals and this can lead to bad habits. I'll start with plain AJAX interaction, low-level

Comment: +1 jquery is good, but @Giacomo how can jQuery's documentation be misleading? People should fully read the docs and use it like it suggests

Comment: The problem are not the docs, the problem is the philosophy of hiding the internals. jquery has no fault, the problem are the people telling "ok let's crap up something in a few mins w/ some copy'n'paste, yeah" that don't know what an XMLHttpRequest is.